# TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable for dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, object, typeerror, iterable

why it is giving 'float' object is not iterable error? when I put nested loop?

```
text = []

for i in df['text']:

    string = ""
    for j in i:
        string += j
    text.append(string)

text[2]
```

Comment: I guess you have NaNs in the df.text and then you try to iterate over this Nan

Comment: No actually  df['text'] has some tweets but this dataset has only one column which is text. It is giving me error when I am using nested for loop..

Answer (score 2):

@miepsik is right, you probably have NaN in `text` column.

Reproducible example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'text': ['Hello', np.nan, 'World']})

text = []
for i in df['text']:
    string = ""
    for j in i:
        string += j
    text.append(string)
```

Output:

```
...
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

To debug your dataframe and find NaN values, you can use:

```
>>> df.loc[df['text'].isna()]
  text
1  NaN
```

What I understand is you iterate on strings (`i`) then loop on each character (`j`) and create a list. I don't know exactly what your dataframe looks like but you can optimize your code with vectorized functions like:

```
>>> df['text'].dropna().tolist()
['Hello', 'World']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot to @Corralien for your solution. now my code is working.

Comment: Yeah @miepsik was right. Thanks for responding.

Comment: I think every problem is important big or small. when someone is giving effort to another person I think now a days it is rear. Sometimes thanks is not enough. I always remember every person in my prayers who helped me in difficult time.